# How can I create a specific time interval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

What I have tried so far ...

```
start_hour = 7
start_minute = 0 * 0.01

end_hour = 17
end_minute = 45 * 0.01

step_time = 25

start_time = start_hour + start_minute
end_time = end_hour + end_minute

if step_time > 59
  step_time = 1 if step_time == 60
  step_time = 1.3 if step_time == 90
  step_time = 2 if step_time == 120
else
  step_time *= 0.01
end

hours = []

(start_time..end_time).step(step_time).map do |x| 
    next if (x-x.to_i) > 0.55
    hours << '%0.2f' % x.round(2).to_s
end

puts hours
```

If I enter the step interval 0, 5, 10, 20, I can get the time interval I want. But if I enter 15, 25, 90, I can't get the right range.

Comment: Could you provide input values and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have:

```
end_hour = 17
end_minute = 45 * 0.01

end_time = end_hour + end_minute
#=> 17.45
```

Although `17.45` *looks* like the correct value, it isn't. 45 minutes is 3 quarters (or 75%) of an hour, so the correct decimal value is `17.75`.

You could change your code accordingly, but working with [decimal hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time#Decimal_hours) is a bit strange. It's much easier to just work with minutes. Instead of turning the minutes into hours, you turn the hours into minutes:

```
start_hour = 7
start_minute = 0

start_time = start_hour * 60 + start_minute
#=> 420

end_hour = 17
end_minute = 45

end_time = end_hour * 60 + end_minute
#=> 1065
```

The total amount of minutes can easily be converted back to hour-minute pairs via [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod):

```
 420.divmod(60)  #=> [7, 0]
1065.divmod(60)  #=> [17, 45]
```

Using the above, we can traverse the range without having to convert the step interval:

```
def hours(start_time, end_time, step_time)
  (start_time..end_time).step(step_time).map do |x|
    '%02d:%02d' % x.divmod(60)
  end
end

hours(start_time, end_time, 25)
#=> ["07:00", "07:25", "07:50", "08:15", "08:40", "09:05", "09:30", "09:55",
#    "10:20", "10:45", "11:10", "11:35", "12:00", "12:25", "12:50", "13:15",
#    "13:40", "14:05", "14:30", "14:55", "15:20", "15:45", "16:10", "16:35",
#    "17:00", "17:25"]

hours(start_time, end_time, 90)
#=> ["07:00", "08:30", "10:00", "11:30", "13:00", "14:30", "16:00", "17:30"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this way, the correct result is always obtained.